# Ensure presentingViewController for a popover is the original presenter

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uicontainerview, uimodalpresentationstyle

I have a container view controller. One of the child view controllers needs to present a popover. The problem is that the popover's `presentingViewController` ends up being the container view controller and not the child view controller that presented it.

*I've set the `definesPresentationContext` property to `true` on the child view controller (and its navigation controller) but that doesn't change anything (that's only useful if the presented controller's `modalPresentationStyle` is `.currentContext` or `overCurrentContext`

The documentation for `UIViewController present(_:animated:completion:)` talks about how the presentation may be from another controller depending on the presentation style. So I'm hoping there is a way to override or intercept that determination so I can ensure, in this case, that the popover's `presentingViewController` is the controller that originally presented it.

I have other functionality in the container view controller related to adapting to changes in size class that are being hindered by this problem.

**Is there any way to ensure a popover's `presentingViewController` is the original presenter?** It's probably related to how the `presentationController` is created but I don't see how to tap into that process.

Below is code that demonstrates the problem. If you wish to replicate the problem, create a new iOS Single View App project in Xcode. Then replace the contents of the provided `ViewController.swift` with the code below. Run on an iPad simulator. A container view controller with one child view controller will be added and a popup will be presented from the child. The debugger console will show some output. Notice how the popup's `presentingViewController` is the container and not the child.

*Note*: While the following is in Swift, Objective-C responses are fine too.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var childViewController: UIViewController!

    override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)

        coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: { (context) in
            self.childViewController.navigationController?.view.frame = CGRect(x: size.width / 2, y: 0, width: size.width / 2, height: size.height)
        }, completion: nil)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        childViewController = UIViewController()
        childViewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Test", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
        let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: childViewController)

        addChildViewController(nav)
        view.addSubview(nav.view)
        nav.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        let popup = UIViewController()
        popup.definesPresentationContext = true
        let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: popup)
        nav.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
        nav.definesPresentationContext = true
        nav.popoverPresentationController?.barButtonItem = childViewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem
        childViewController.present(nav, animated: true) {
            print("Popup displayed")
            print("container: \(self)")
            print("child: \(self.childViewController), child.nav: \(self.childViewController.navigationController)")
            print("presentingViewController: \(nav.presentingViewController)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The only place I know where this distinction is drawn is `func presentationController(forPresented presented: UIViewController, 
    presenting: UIViewController?, source: UIViewController)`

Comment: @matt And that's only called when the `modalPresentationStyle` is set to `custom`. I dread the thought of needing to completely replicate the popover style with my own custom implementation just to get the needed `presentingViewController`.

Comment: Any solution so far? I am facing with the similar issue.

Comment: I'm facing similar issue. Any solution?

Comment: @rmaddy where did you end up landing on this?